# Forgot to Cancel My Appointment

Tags: visa, germany, philippine-citizens, interview

I am applying for a family reunion visa and forgot to cancel my appointment with the German Embassy in Manila. I cannot cancel it anymore. What do I do? I have been calling the embassy but no answer and I sent an email as well (but it will take time for them to respond). I need to book another appointment and it is not allowing me because of the previous appointment set up.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the world of embassies - I'm still waiting on a reply from the British one from early 2009 ;)

All you can really do is persist. If it's possible to visit the embassy in person, that sometimes helps, but otherwise look for other outlets that they might have (not all will), including:

- Facebook page
- twitter
- multiple phone numbers
- linkedin contacts
- address to send mail (express mail may help)